# How to use foreach array value out side of loop

Tags: php

```
foreach($reciveValue as $value){

    echo $value.",";// Result: based on user input like:10,11,12,13,14
  }
echo $value; // Result: 14
```

the result inside loop is: 10,11,12,13,14

and outside loop is : 14

I want to use all value outside of loop

Comment: If you are just concatenating your values, just `implode(".", $reciveValue)` will do.

Comment: @Thamilan OP want `,` so `implode(",", $reciveValue)`

Comment: @cske Sory a typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$value = '';
foreach($reciveValue as $val){
    $value .= $val.",";// Result: based on user input like:10,11,12,13,14
}
echo rtrim($value, ',');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get your array values comma seperated

```
implode(",", $reciveValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

> @Support Techcherry if you want to use all values of an array outside
>   the loop then you can use implode() function, below is an example
>   understand

```
<?php
    $reciveValue = array(10,11,12,13,14);   // suppose this is your array 
    foreach($reciveValue as $value){

        echo $value.",";// Result: based on user input like:10,11,12,13,14
      }
      echo "<br>";
    echo implode(',', $reciveValue);  // here implode() function convert the array value in the string form 
?>
```

try it, it will help you

Answer (score 0):

thanks to everyone for posting answer 
every answer is very helpful for me 
but finally i got my solution

```
    $result="";
    foreach($reciveValue as $value)
    {
        $result=$value.",".$result;

    }   
    echo $result;
```